# Adverbs of place, agents and adverbs of time in passive voice

Tags: passive-voice

Could you explain to me this grammar point, please?
Active voice: "Someone cleans the room every day."
Passive voice:

> a. The room is cleaned by someone every day
> b. The room is cleaned every day by someone
> c. The room is cleaned every day.

All the cases are true?

Answer (score 1):

All your examples are grammatical examples of passive-voice forms of the original sentence, although option C loses some information.

Whether they are *true* is another matter.

Answer (score 0):

I personally think C is the best answer. This is because the agent or the performer of the action is not clear. Therefore, we tend not to bring back the unclear subjects in passive sentence.